# Completion of the rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I am preparing to embark on the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to a p-adic absolute. However, I thought I should start with the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to the usual absolute value first. I am looking for feed back on the following steps

1. Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$
2. Find a possible limit, say $x$, in $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$
3. Show that $x_n$ does in fact converge to $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completion is usually CONSTRUCTED starting from the rational. Therefore you cannot "find" the limit of a Cauchy sequence within the rationals: for most of such sequences this limit does not exist within $\mathbb{Q}$. The steps to construct the reals or the $p$-adics are the following:

- consider the set $C$ of all Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$ and show that this set becomes a commutative ring if one defines addition and multiplication componentwise.
- show that the set $N$ of nullsequences is a maximal ideal of $C$; therefore $C/N$ is a field.
- extend the absolute value continously to $C/N$ and show that $C/N$ is complete with respect to that absolute value.